# Using only one servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'am making a web page with a login system and backoffice page. The problem is, both use the method "doPost" (the login use to autenticate and the backoffice use to insert data in db). How can I use only one servlet for both? I'am asking this because both use doPost, so I made two servlet's.

Comment: whats the problem in using multiple servlets?

Comment: I would begin by learning a web framework, Spring or Struts or one of those. These do much of the heavy lifting for you, for example parsing the URL and the request parameters and routing the request to the correct method.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to use a single servlet, you should implement [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). For this, you will parse the request URL and decide which action should be performed:

```
public class MySingleServlet extends Servlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        String url = request.getPathInfo();
        //returns the action to handle
        Action action = ActionFactory.getAction(url);
        action.process(request, response);
    }
}
```

This involves an `Action` interface/abstract class and an `ActionFactory` that will parse the URL and return the right implementation to handle the actions to do.

Another more naive and harder-to-maintain implementation is by sending an `action` parameter. This may be a problem because an attacker may use a proxy and change the `action` parameter before sending the request to the URL. If this is a recognized valid `action`, and the attacker knows what to send, then you're in trouble.

Note that there are MVC frameworks that already implement Front Controller Pattern like Spring MVC and JSF, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel unless it is for learning purposes (otherwise, you should use a library that already implements this).

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra parameter (e.g. `action`) in your post method

- retrieved from a hidden form field, if you are using forms, or
- added with a simple `&action='value'` to your request if using xml http request

and based on its value perform the appropriate actions:

```
if (action.equals("auth"))
{
     // authenticate
}
else if (action.equals("backoffice"))
{
    // db update
}
```

Comment: but there is at least need of one other serevlet to get to know na what is action is called..

Comment: @Krishna no, the action is just another input parameter near username and password in the case of authentication.

Comment: Please note, that this approach is the learning one from the categories mentioned by @Luiggi Mendoza. Using a pattern or a library / framework that already implemented and integrated it is always the best choice in a production environment.

Comment: @rekazeru its okey i got it the parameter which will be send by the user according to the that method will call .:D

Answer (score 0):

You can get pathInfo from request object based on that you route the request.